# Internet Explorer 8+ compatibility

Tags: internet-explorer-8, yesod

I have based my project on the current scaffolding from Yesod 0.10. I've gone into scary territory. While my code works just fine in both Firefox and Chrome, my workplace requires that it also works in IE. Well, it doesn't. It just gives me a "Webpage cannot be displayed" error. I'm using default layout, yet it still complains. Below find the source that Yesod generates.

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 7]>          
<html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]--><!--[if IE 8]>    
<html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Socko homepage</title>
  <meta name="description" content>
  <meta name="author" content>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://10.5.125.201:3000/static/tmp/zfWtkHUp.css">
  <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">    
  </script><![endif]-->
  <script>document.documentElement.className = 
  document.documentElement.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js');
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
  <header></header>
  <div id="main" role="main"><h1> </h1>
  <p>
  <a href="http://10.5.125.201:3000/auth/login">You must login to schedule a test.</a>  
  </p>
  <footer>Barracuda Networks All Rights Reserved</footer>
  <script src="http://10.5.125.201:3000/static/js/modernizr.js?-nhfNco9"></script>  
  <script>yepnope({load:["http://10.5.125.201:3000/static/tmp/1B2M2Y8A.js"]})</script>  
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
  </div>
  <!-- Prompt IE 6 users to install Chrome Frame. Remove this if you want to support IE 
  6.  chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started -->
  <!--[if lt IE 7 ]>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/chrome-frame/1.0.3/CFInstall.min.js">   
  </script>
  <script>window.attachEvent('onload',function(){CFInstall.check({mode:'overlay'})})   
  </script><![endif]--></body></html>
```

Comment: We did traffic analysis, and we now believe this is an http problem, not an html problem. Which makes me wonder about warp. New question. What would be a good way to test warp 1.1 against IE 8+?

Comment: Did you figure out what was the problem? I'm browsing the yesod tag and this being unanswered is kind of scary..

Comment: what versions of IE did you have problems with? Nobody else has reported IE problems. Please bring unanswered SO problems to the mail list.

Comment: I solved this by putting warp behind nginx. When I get some free time I can easily duplicate the problem.

Comment: @MichaelLitchard could you elaborate more on the problem? I want to develop something and want it cross platform as well

Comment: @pyCthon If you are using Warp I imagine the problem is fixed by now. I never did identify the exact problem. I just had a hunch that xginx would automagically fix it, and it did.